# Search XLM document for string within a tag

Tags: python, lxml

I need to search for the id "1438" in an XML webpage and return the text in certain elements below it such as YES, 10:00, NO. I never know the location of the data/tags thus I always need to search the entire document.

```
<type="home">
    <name="wo" id="1438">
        <category name="m1" id="2">
        <date="17.06.2013" time="">
           <status="YES" time="10:00" id="654657">
               <winner="NO" _won="0" id="2714"/>
               <winner="YES" _won="0" id="2943"/>
    </won>
```

Thus far I have

```
result = urllib.urlopen("URL")
html = result.read()
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(html), parser)

doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)

print doc.xpath(u'.//[text()="1438"]/text()')
```

However I just get the following error

```
 lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

I guess that my xpath expression is wrong but after searching for examples I've not really found any clear tutorial, if anyone know of any (newbie friendly) examples I would be most grateful to be directed towards them. I would use BS4, however I have quite a number to process and I understand lxml is much quicker.. Sorry if this is a stupid question!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
doc.xpath(u'//*[id="1438"]/text()')
```